# An answer a full hour after the question was closed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, closed-questions

There was a [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50530/7475) closed today for being too homeworky. Closing happened ‘1 hour ago’ as of now.

Right a few seconds ago, an answer to said question was posted (labelled with ‘1 minute ago’ right now, but that changes faster).

What happened here?

---

**Edit:** As per one of the many SE updates since this has been posted, it is no longer possible to post an answer once a question is closed. The site will no longer allow it.

Comment: What happened here is that you posted a [duplicate](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3190/). *Rimshot*

Comment: I've seen a least one similar question on meta's recently, either here or on Physics. Basically, if you start answering a question, your answering does not time out for something like 4 hours. This lets you compose a nice answer, and accounts for things like your internet connection going down. The downside is that you can hit 'submit' after the question has been closed, whether you know it or not. Generally it is considered a small price to pay for dealing with the internet.

Comment: Awww, you removed that beautiful MathJax code and didn’t allow any reviews =C I was so hoping to see what actually happens on the user’s side when my question gets flagged as such. Oh well. Can go back to work then. (@Mart)

Comment: Sorry, but blame @PhMgBr for not flagging. As for the MathJax: No.